# display discount banner only on home page at the top in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i am creating a front end of a website using ReactJs and i want to display the discount banner only at the top of homepage and not at any other pages of routing..what should i do?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App ">
     <Title />
      <Navigation />
         <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/t-shirt" component={ViewTshirt} />
            <Route exact path="/new-products" component={ViewAllProduct} />
            <Route exact path="/product-detail" component={DetailPage} />
            <Route component={notfound} />
         </Switch>
      </div>
      <Footer />
     </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You should be able to put `<Route exact path="/" component={DiscordBanner} />` at the top of your App div.

Comment: thanks a lot..it perfectly helped me

Comment: Great, you're welcome :)